# Create a subquery with spring data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection for status update of an order service. Each document in this collection is a new update for this Order.

The Document is like this:

```
{
    "_id": "xxx",
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "notificationDate": ISODate("2019-06-01T20:25:43.280Z"),
    "description": "Something"
}
```

I must found every order with no update in this month, so I made this query:

```
db.notificationData.find({"$and": [
    {"orderNumber": {"$nin" : 
        db.notificationData.find({notificationDate: {"$gt": ISODate("2019-06-01") }})
                .map(function(data) { return data.orderNumber})
    }},
    {notificationDate: {"$lt": ISODate("2019-06-01") }}
]});
```

There is a way to get the same result using Spring Data MongoDB??

Comment: I don't understand the need for the "inner" query, isn't filtering for notificationDate < startOfMonth enough?

Comment: cause I want only orders without new updates after this date ...
If order number 1 have an entry after date 2019-06-01, this order will be discarded from result ...

Comment: Ok, understood, but then it's the second condition in the $and that seems redundant, or I'm missing something? Anyway  to answer your question, this is basically two queries executed separately in mongo shell  first the one to get the order ids, then the "outer" one with the filtering on order id. It's not a subquery as in SQL. And that'a how you can implement it with Spring Data, first get order Ids, then use the returned collection in the $nin filter.